# didBecomeActive un-pauses game

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, appdelegate

I am pausing my game with a willResignActive notification, and it seems to pause the game, but when didBecomeActive is called, it seems to un-pause on its own.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(applicationWillResign)
     name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
     object:NULL];

- (void) applicationWillResign {

    self.scene.view.paused = TRUE;
    NSLog(@"About to lose focus");
}
```

How do I get it to stay paused? Do I actually need to pause it in my AppDelegate?

Comment: That code is from another question here.

Comment: Apparently, with Xcode 6, sprite kit automatically pauses the scene and view when your app loses focus and resumes (un-pauses) when the app enters the foreground. Sprite kit resumes the game after applicationDidBecomeActive is called, so I don't think adding code to the AppDelegate will work.

Comment: so will I have to make sure it is still paused when it resumes?

Comment: I'm not sure what is called after applicationDidBecomeActive, so I don't know where to add code to pause the view/scene.

Comment: Override the paused setter for the scene to check whether this is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to keep the view paused after returning from background mode. It's a bit of a hack, but it does work.

1) Define an SKView subclass with a boolean named stayPaused...

```
    @interface MyView : SKView

    @property BOOL stayPaused;

    @end

    @implementation MyView

    // Override the paused setter to conditionally un-pause the view
    - (void) setPaused:(BOOL)paused
    {
        if (!_stayPaused || paused) {
            // Call the superclass's paused setter
            [super setPaused:paused];
        }
        _stayPaused = NO;
    }

    - (void) setStayPaused
    {
        _stayPaused = YES;
    }

    @end
```

2) In the storyboard, change the class of the view to MyView

3) In the view controller, define the view as MyView

4) Add a notifier to set the stayPaused flag

```
    @implementation GameViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Define view using the subclass
        MyView * skView = (MyView *)self.view;

        // Add an observer for a method that sets the stay pause flag when notified
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:skView selector:@selector(setStayPaused)
                                                     name:@"stayPausedNotification" object:nil];

        ...
```

5) In AppDelegate.m, post a notification to set the stay paused flag when the app becomes active

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"stayPausedNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: This does work, but takes a lot of tweaking. I also found if you pause the game again, and add a timer on the return from background notification, you can resume when the timer expires.