# What is the best way to create a pause menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to make a menu that gets activated by tapping a SKSpriteNode, then pauses everything in my game except for the resume and restart button and also gets activated when the user leaves the app.

I'm currently doing this by having a bool call isPaused and all the methods only get activated when isPaused is set to NO. Whenever the pause node is touched it gets set to YES and everything stops. This, however, causes me a lot of trouble, for instance, when didEnterBackground is called I make that call the method that pauses the scene, but when you reopen the app the pause menu is not there.

I want to know what the best way of doing this is.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to use a 'game-layer' node. It's like a super-node which contains all the nodes from your game.

The trick is, that if you then call gameLayer.paused = true, all sub-nodes also will pause, because the pause function works recursively.

for example:

**Swift**:

```
var gameLayer = SKNode()

var node1 = SKSpriteNode()
var node2 = SKSpriteNode()

var specialNode = SKSpriteNode()

gameLayer.addChild(node1)
gameLayer.addChild(node2)

gameLayer.pause = true

//node1 and node2 will pause also
```

**Objective-C**

```
SKSpriteNode *node1 = [SKSpriteNode new];
SKSpriteNode *node2 = [SKSpriteNode new];
SKSpriteNode *specialNode = [SKSpriteNode new];

[gameLayer addChild: node1];
[gameLayer addChild: node2];

gameLayer.paused = TRUE;
```

Now you can call `gameLayer.paused = true` where ever you want and pause all the nodes at once.

Comment: Could you do it in objective-c

Comment: Okay, so another thing: how do I open the pause menu aitomatically when leaving the app

Comment: Could you check out my other question (Why is my SKAction not working properly?) It is a weird problem and no one is responding

Answer (score 1):

To continue your train of thought, use the BOOL in the update method like this:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if(isPaused) {
        // handle only processing during a pause
    } else {
        // handle processing while not paused
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if we have some calculations in didSymulatePhysics, didEvaluateActions etc... Then we should check if isPaused at multiple places. Is there some way to pause a game only at one place ? By pausing the game I am considering pausing by taping pause button as well as pausing because of incoming phone call.

Comment: @Whirlwind - That goes without saying. If you have code in any of the other frame update methods than the same code needs to be implemented. If you want to pause "the game play code" while still being able to process pause methods, like buttons, than the above is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my question here: [didBecomeActive un-pauses game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321347/didbecomeactive-un-pauses-game)

I can see if I can post my code (under NDA) when I get to my computer. The answer does work, and my comment about adding a timer works well also.